# Same result from stateful, stateless and singleton EJB beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, stateless, stateful

i am trying to make a simple examples of @Stateful, @Stateless and @Singleton EJB beans to help me better understand the differences. The problem is that there is no difference at all when I annotate the bean with any of @Stateful, @Stateless or @Singleton annotations.

Here is the bean:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


    @Stateful
    public class Bean {
        private int counter = 0;

        public int getCounter(){
            return counter++;
        }  
    }
```

And here is the Servlet Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javaeetutorial.converter.ejb.Bean;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/")
public class Client extends HttpServlet{

    @EJB
    Bean bean;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html lang=\"en\">");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>test</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet ConverterServlet at " +
                request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        try {
            out.println("<form method=\"get\">");
            out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("<p>" + bean.getCounter() + "</p>");    
            out.println("<p>" + bean + "</p>"); 
        } finally {
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

The expected results for me are:

@Statefull - when every different client press the button to see counting from 0

@Singleton - when any client press the button to see only one counting

@Stateless - i don't know what exactly to expect

Comment: Describe the tests you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the webservlet is instantiated once (or at least not once per request, that is what you would need to see clearly the difference), so it is the bean instance. Therefore, there is no difference which type of bean are you using (stateful, stateless, singleton), since the Bean instance is depending always on the same servlet instance.

If you would use a **requestScoped** resource, with the **singleton** annotation you would count how many times have been the counter requested (all requests share the same instance), with the **stateful** you would see how many times a client have requested the counter, and with **stateless** would depend. However, because the counter is a state, it make no sense to use a statless bean (look at the name). You can understand stateless as a *pooled* ejb, so each time that the bean is required the server will fetch an instance of the stateless pool. An advantage is the performance of the bean, since they are already created into the pool (check the stateless pool configuration) they are really fast to use.

You can found some more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ejb/session.html).

Answer (score 1):

The expected results are:

- @Stateful - Stateful session beans have timeouts, so you should **never** inject a stateful session bean into a long-lived object such as a servlet.  Instead, you should only look them up and use them (possibly by inserting the reference into an HttpSession).  The expected result is the bean instance and its counter will be shared by all requests, and if you make concurrent requests, each one will block waiting for access to the stateful session bean (try adding a sleep to the getCounter method, and then make requests from multiple browser tabs/windows).  If you do not make a request for some amount of time, the bean will be removed, which will cause all subsequent requests to fail; you can use `@StatefulTimeout(value=1, unit=TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to easily observe this.
- @Singleton - The bean instance and its counter will be shared by all requests.  By default, singletons use container-managed concurrency, so only one request at a time will be allowed in a method.  Again, you can add a sleep to the getCounter method to observe this.
- @Stateless - Depending on your application server's pooling configuration, multiple bean instances might be created as needed for concurrent requests and bean instances might be reused across requests.  Again, you can add a sleep to the getCounter method and make requests from multiple browser tabs/windows to observe this.  Stateless session beans are intended to be used to encapsulate other EJB services (e.g., transactions, security, scheduling, etc.), so member variables should only be used to cache state that can be used regardless of the client (e.g., caching references to DataSource, UserTransaction, etc.), not to store state.